# Use Pandas to grab certain rows and certain columns from a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How would I go about looking up a specific value in a column, then selecting a subset of the column values in that row in pandas?

I have a CSV with a column full of US state names and columns with attributes about each state, but I only want certain values about the states I'm looking up.

For example, there are 50 rows (for the 50 states) and 20 columns with various data about each state, and I want to select Colorado and Florida and only 5 of the column values for those states.

Here is my code that I want to modify:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
 
myList = []
 
path = "/path/to/source/files/*.csv"
 
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    row = df.loc[df['Province_State'] == 'Pennsylvania']
 
    # Put the date in, derived from the CSV name
    dateFromFilename = os.path.basename(fname).replace('.csv','')
    row['Date'] = dateFromFilename
 
    myList.append(row)
    print(row)
 
concatList = pd.concat(myList, sort=True)
 
concatList.to_csv('/path/to/output.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `isin` and pass list of columns to `loc`:

```
myList = []

path = "/path/to/source/files/*.csv"

col_lists = ['col1','col2','col3']
 
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)

    # changes here
    row = df.loc[df['Province_State'].isin('Florida', 'Colorado'),
                 col_list]

    # pivot
    row = (row.assign(idx=row.groupby('Province_State').cumcount()).     
              .pivot(index='idx', columns='Province_State')
          )
    # rename
    row.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in row.columns]          

    # Put the date in, derived from the CSV name
    dateFromFilename = os.path.basename(fname).replace('.csv','')
    row['Date'] = dateFromFilename
 
    myList.append(row)
    print(row)
 
concatList = pd.concat(myList, sort=True)
```

Comment: How would I rename the columns as I grab them?  Because I will end up with two `col1`s for each of state.  I need to end up with `Florida_col1`, `Colorado_col1`, etc.

Comment: There was a syntax error here, i think, which I fixed: `row = (row.assign(idx=row.groupby('Province_State').cumcount()).pivot(index='idx', columns='Province_State')` but I am still getting one here, which I don't understand: `row.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in row.columns]`

Comment: Before that line `row` has two-level columns. See Question/Anwer 10/11 in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe) for details.

Comment: So I need to replace `x,y` with actual column names?

Comment: No, that’s what the for loop is for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224532/discussion-between-reallymemorable-and-quang-hoang).